# При выводе содержания переменной в терминале pycharm русские слова нормально выглядят а в файле только ромбики

Tags: pycharm, encoder

Пытался изменить настройки в кодировке IDE, писал в начале кода тип кодировки, пытался прям в коде перекодировать, выходило еще хуже

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-sig -*-
import requests
import os
import sys
import chardet
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.vesti.ru/'

headers = {
"accept": "*/*",
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.141 YaBrowser/22.3.4.731 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.text
print(src)

with open("index.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(src)
```

Answer (score 0):

На Windows нужно явно указывать кодировку при сохранении файла.

```
with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(src)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло